# How to dynamically create table in database using greendao or ORMLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, greendao

How to dynamically create table in database using greendao or ORMLite? I want to create new table in database when user pressed button, for each new table in database, data model is same but I need table with diffrent name. Is that possible ?

Comment: and what for? add second table: `THETABLE` with `id` and `name` columns. Then add `THETABLE_id` in first table ... now you can store all of those data in first table (instead adding new table you are addin the row to THETABLE and use it id(as THETABLE_id) to insert to first table

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that is not solution for my problem. I have collection of Dictionarie's , i create table where I store data about each dictionary (dictionary name, author ...) but I need when user want to instal new dictionary to create new table with name of that dictionary, in new table I want to store word's for that dictionary.

Comment: it is ... make table Words(id, word, translation, dictionaryID) and table Dictionary(id, name, author, etc.) ... you don't need new Words table for every dictionary ... just use dictionaryID foreign key from Dictionary table...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concerning greendao:

It's not possible to dynamically create a new table. With greendao the code for handling your database is created on your development station by a J2SE-Application (using the daogenerator).

### Concerning Ormlite:

I haven't been using Ormlite until now, but I doupt that generating new tables at runtime is possible.

### Conclusion:

IMHO a database design, where you have to create new tables at runtime is bad practice, because you won't beable to benefit from ORM-frameworks. A design like that is also very difficult to maintain (if not impossible) and/or to test. On top of that a design like that may be difficult to understand for other developers as it is really uncommon.
Thus you should redesign your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLite

```
public void createUserTable(DatabaseOperations d, String user) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String CREATE_TABLE_NEW_USER = "CREATE TABLE " + user + " (" + UserInfo.NOTES + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NEW_USER);
    db.close();
}
```